# C++ Triangle-Plane intersection to line

Tags: c++, geometry, intersection

Here's a simplified version of my triangle object and related objects:

```
class line{
   public:
    double x1;
    double y1;
    double x2;
    double y2;
}
class vertex{
  public:
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
}; 
class triangle{
    vertex a;
    vertex b;
    vertex c;
  public:
    line *intersection(double z_axis){
        line *l = new line;

        //intersection code here

        return l;
    }
};
```

What I need to happen is for the intersection function to return the line where the triangle and the plane parallel to the x and y axis at the given z axis. All the sample code I've looked at either assumes having a force normal or returns doesn't return quite what I need. I'd really appreciate some insight on how to go about doing this in an optimal way. I'm having trouble making sense of the Plane-Plane intersection formal math solutions.

Thanks in advance,

Max

Comment: How come your axis is just a double? Moreover, you can post some code you have tried. WE will try to correct that, in case.

Comment: I haven't got anything working really worth posting. The z axis is just a double because the z for the plane is the point and the x and y are always 0.

Comment: You can get pointers from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142469/determining-the-intersection-of-a-triangle-and-a-plane

Comment: You could probably get some code (or at least ideas) on [geometric tools](http://www.geometrictools.com/).

Comment: I'm taking a look at the links you guys posted. I'll update the post once I make some headway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should handle different situations:

1) there is no intersection. (for each vertex: z_axis > vertex.z) or (for each vertex: z_axis < vertex.z)

2) the triangle lies in the z=z_axis plane (for each vertex: z_axis = vertex.x). This is awkward for doubles but 0 or some powers of two or some nice binary fractions are represented precisely.

3) one vertex (let's call it P) is below and two vertices (Q, R) are above the z=z_axis plane (or vice versa)

here you'll be able to find the intersections.
Your problem will be broken down to find intersection of line PQ and PR with the plane z=z_axis.

4) one or two vertices lie on the z=z_axis plane.

The intersections here are trivial, but they may still be computed the same way as in point 3.

Is it clear? You may start implementing...

Comment: In case 3 the intercept theorem will be helpful